# AutocompleteArrayInput isn't working in 2.4.0

Tags: react-admin

I am using React-Admin, and I use the : `<AutocompleteArrayInput />`.
This morning, I updated my React-Admin to the 2.4.0 version; and my component isn't working anymore. Nothing changed about this component in the documentation.

Here is my code :

```
<ReferenceArrayInput source="myJson['myKey']" reference="myTable" alwaysOn>
  <AutocompleteArrayInput optionText="id"/>
</ReferenceArrayInput>
```

And I get this error : 
`TypeError: selectedIds.forEach is not a function`
If you see something suspicious in my code please, explain me.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bug. For a temporary fix, add `defaultValue={[]}` to your ReferenceArrayInput

Comment: Please add code blocks around suggestions, or a snippet of what your solution